# integration 3 dimensions by generalizing the method of rectangle

Tags: python, math, 3d, numerical-integration

```
def RectanglesPointMilieu(f,a,b,n):
    interval = 1.* (b-a) / n
    sumfct = 0
    for i in np.arange(a,b,interval):
            sumfct += f(i + interval/2.)
    return interval * sumfct
```

how do i change it into 3 dimensions calculation?

```
def rec3(f,X1,X2,X3,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,N1,N2,N3):
    interval1 = 1.* (b1-a1) / N1
    interval2 = 1.* (b2-a2) / N2
    interval3 = 1.* (b3-a3) / N3
    Sum1 = 0
    Sum2 = 0
    Sum3 = 0
    for i in np.arange(a1,b1,interval1):
        Sum1 += f((X1[i]+ interval1))
    for i in np.arange(a2,b2,interval2):
        Sum2 += f((X2[i]+ interval2))
    for i in np.arange(a3,b3,interval3):
        Sum3 += f((X3[i]+ interval3))

    return interval * float(Sum)
```

i did something like this but i'm just so lost and confused...i don't know how to continue...[I'm new at this]

```
def rec3(f,X1,X2,X3,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,N1,N2,N3):
    interval1 = 1.* (b1-a1) / N1
    interval2 = 1.* (b2-a2) / N2
    interval3 = 1.* (b3-a3) / N3
    Sum = 0
    for i in np.arange(a1,b1,interval1):
        for j in np.arange(a2,b2,interval2):
            for k in np.arange(a3,b3,interval3):
                Sum += f((X1[i]+ interval1),(X2[j]+ interval2),(X3[k]+ interval3))
    return interval1 * interval2 * interval3 * float(Sum)
```

with 
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

```
#def TEST_Q2():
    # Créer des tableaux
N = 1E5
X1 = rd.normal(0,1,N)
X2 = rd.normal(0,1,N)
X3 = rd.normal(0,1,N)
XX1 = X1 * np.sqrt(2)
XX2 = X2 * np.sqrt(2)
XX3 = X3 * 2.


def fct(a,b,c): # [x1**2 * x2**4 * exp(-x1**2 -x2**2 -2x3**2)]
    return ((a**2. * b**4.)/32.) * np.exp(-a**2./2.-b**2./2.-c**2./2.)




# Calculer l’intégrale
F = fct(XX1,XX2,XX3)
print rec3(F,XX1,XX2,XX3,0,0,0,1,1,1,N,N,N)


# Rlt = 11.8416033988
```

i use this as my Test

Comment: What is your definition of `f`?, as it can you provide an example of an `f` you're using?  And what is in the arrays `X1`, `X2`, and `X3` you're passing and what are you trying to do with them?

Comment: Again I'm not familiar with python, but it strikes me as being odd that you're trying to index arrays (`X1`, `X2`, `X3`) with values which may not be non-negative integers (`i`, `j`, `k`).  `i`, `j`, and `k` will in general not be non-negative integers.  Does python permit that?

Comment: i chose f = x1^2 * x2^4 * exp(-x1^2 -x2^2 -2*x3^2)

Comment: i basically just to need to write a fonction that works for calculating 3 dimensional integrals while using the method of rectangle

Comment: The values X1, X2 and X3 you're passing aren't arrays, they're just scalar values, but in the integration routine you're indexing them like arrays, so you're getting an error indicating this to be the case.  Take another look at what I wrote below and use it more or less as I wrote it to see if it works... that is, don't pass in the arrays or use them inside the integration.  They shouldn't be necessary unless you're doing something more complicated than the integration in the first example.

Comment: i'm not sure, shouldn't it be arrays in this case?

Comment: I don't think you need any arrays, and even if you do, you haven't declared any arrays, just scalars.  The integration method in this case calculates the integration points on the fly.  In your case you could pre-compute the components of the integration points to provide a bit of an improvement in performance (though that may be premature at this point), but that's not what you're doing.  Again, you're declaring scalar values but trying to use them like arrays.  That's why python is generating the error you're seeing.  See my update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [multidimensional numerical integration](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=multidimensional%20numerical%20integration).  In order to perform such on an `n`-dimensional function, you will need to use `n` nested loops.  In your case where `n=3`, the naive approach is to simply do something like:

```
def rec3(f,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,N1,N2,N3):
    interval1 = 1.* (b1-a1) / N1
    interval2 = 1.* (b2-a2) / N2
    interval3 = 1.* (b3-a3) / N3
    Sum = 0

    for x in np.arange(a1,b1,interval1):
        for y in np.arange(a2,b2,interval2):
            for z in np.arange(a3,b3,interval3):
                Sum += f(x+interval1/2., y+interval2/2., z+interval3/2.)

    return abs(interval1*interval2*interval3)*Sum
```

I don't know python very well, so there may be a syntax error in there, so use with care.

There are other approaches which may yield better results.  You can try a few of the links in the search I suggested above to see if there is something more appropriate for your particular need.

**UPDATE**:  Here is how it would be used:

```
N = 1E3

def fct(a,b,c):
    return ((a**2. * b**4.)/32.) * np.exp(-a**2./2.-b**2./2.-c**2./2.)

print rec3(fct,0,0,0,1,1,1,N,N,N)
```

Comment: thank you, but i have [TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable] for  Sum += (f((X1[i]+ interval1),(X2[j]+ interval2),(X3[k]+ interval3))) what did i do wrong for this line?